# Send mail by SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, email

i am not getting this store procedure , can you tell where is it "master..xp_sendmail"

i have send the mail when any insertion take place in  particular table like "Emp"

Comment: It is supposed to exist in MASTER database. Look under procedures for MASTER database. Thats where it is supposed to be. For configuring it to work, refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft you should not use xp_sendmail anymore. Use this instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=SQL.90).aspx

As for the process of sending the emails... I would decouple the insert and the sending of the emails. You could have a SQL Server job that polls for new entries in a table and sends the emails if needed. This job could be sheduled to run every 5 minutes.

**Note from MS:**

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. To send mail from SQL
>   Server, use Database Mail.

EDIT: incorporated the usefull links from the comment of adolf garlic

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3626056/Database-Mail-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3626056/Database-Mail-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm       http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/  good old penil dave, he always cums up with the goods. etc.